# LoL crashes after champion selection

Tags: games

I am running League of Legends via WINE, and it works well up to champion selection. Upon champion selection it crashes and won't connect to game.

Comment: I use wine 1.7.19 and have PlayOnLinux, but it crashes after still. How do you test the program via Terminal, or what can I do to try to isolate the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to run LoL on Ubuntu is `PlayOnLinux` since they do all the fiddly config settings for you.  For example, I'm not sure if this is still the case, but originally with vanilla `wine1.7` the game would crash on opening the shop.

1. Install PlayOnLinux, e.g.: `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`
2. Open PlayOnLinux and click the "Install" button
3. Make sure the "Testing" box is checked
4. Search for "League of Legends"
5. Select it and click "Install"

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in Wine 1.6, which is the current stable version of Wine. According to the [Wine AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141&iTestingId=86762), LoL has a Gold rating when using Wine 1.7. Wine 1.7 is the current development branch, but I've been using it for a while and haven't had any issues with it. Therefore, upgrading Wine to version 1.7 should work to fix the problem.

1. Open a terminal
2. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa && sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

Then, reference that link in order to get LoL working properly (looks like there's a lot of "fixes" that have to be implemented before the game will actually run properly).